# Get grooveshark songId from url

Tags: api, grooveshark

I am using the grooveshark API and i would like to find a sondId from url. So i've url:

```
http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/T4+Song/2IsoC7?src=5
```

I extract the "id" in url:

```
2IsoC7
```

But, unlike albums and playlists  where ids are directly displayeds in Url:

```
http://grooveshark.com/#!/album/Sexplosive+Locomotive/3624474
http://grooveshark.com/album/Sexplosive+Locomotive/3624474
http://grooveshark.com/#!/playlist/Punish+Yourself/58054955
http://grooveshark.com/playlist/Punish+Yourself/58054955
```

I don't know how find songId... I've try [getSongIDFromTinysongBase62](http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/public_api/v3/#getSongIDFromTinysongBase62) but not work.

How determine songID with grooveshark API ? Thank's !

Answer (score 3):

There are some Grooveshark methods that are not included in the Official API docs, but there are a [few](https://github.com/sosedoff/grooveshark) [repos](https://github.com/koehlma/pygrooveshark) that document the Unofficial API and include these methods. The method you're looking for is `getSongFromToken`.

It requires `country` and `token` as parameters (`token` is `"2IsoC7"` in your case). You also need to set `header.client` to `"htmlshark"`.

Here's a sample cURL request:

```
curl 'http://grooveshark.com/more.php?getSongFromToken' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-binary '{"header":{"client":"htmlshark","clientRevision":"20130520","uuid":"[YOUR-UUID]","session":"[YOUR-SESSION]","token":"[YOUR-SESSION-TOKEN]"},"method":"getSongFromToken","parameters":{"token":"fESpf","country":{"ID":223,"CC1":0,"CC2":0,"CC3":0,"CC4":1073741824,"DMA":534,"IPR":0}}}'
```

That should give you something looking like this:

```
"header": { 
    "session":"[YOUR-SESSION]",
    "serviceVersion":"20100903",
    "prefetchEnabled":true
},
"result": {
    "SongID":"25134723",
    "Name":"T4 Song",
    "Flags":"0",
    "EstimateDuration":"227",
    "AlbumID":"3624474",
    "AlbumName":"Sexplosive Locomotive",
    "CoverArtFilename":"3624474.jpg",
    "ArtistName":"Punish Yourself",
    "ArtistID":"249162"
}
```

Unfortunately some of these variables are a little poorly named. `token` inside of `header` is your session token. `token` inside of `parameters` is the id of the song you're looking up.

Hope that helps!